# Using enter in an if statement

Tags: python-3.x

```
    Again = str(input("\nPlay again?\n"))
    if Again == "yes" or Again == "Yes":
```

In this code I want to add the enter button as another input possibility but I am unsure of how to accomplish this.

Comment: You could test for `not Again` :)

Comment: @Liam W you should accept answers that you consider as being the most helpful to your questions.

Comment: @LiamW  I noticed that you normally don't accept answers when you ask questions. It is your personal choice, but it's a good practice to accept the best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for an empty string, see code below:

```
Again = str(input("\nPlay again?\n"))
if Again == "yes" or Again == "Yes" or Again == '':
```

and you could also do something like that which will provide flexibility:

```
Again = str(input("\nPlay again?\n"))
possible_values = {'y','yes',''}
if Again.lower() in possible_values:
```

Behind the scene here is what happens when you're using input:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that.

So when a user will only press enter, it will result in an empty string which we can compare using this `''`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Empty string is probably a less confusing phrasing.

Comment: Also, could you explain why?

Comment: @Mad Physicist Thank you for your advice I will update accordingly! really appreciate the input